# What Is Causing Infinite While Loop

Tags: c++, while-loop

I am creating a game for two people to play to guess a number, I had it working with an if statement, but if player 2 gets it wrong I would like them to be able to guess again until they get it right. I decided to use a while loop, but I am getting an infinite loop of text, what can I do to stop it?

Here is my code: (I have commented out the if statement while working on the while loop)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int player1; //Number variable 1
    int player2; //Number variable 2

    cout << "Player 1 type in a number between 1 and 100: "; //Asks player to enter a number
    cin  >> player1;
    system("CLS");

    cout << "Player 2 guess the number between 1 and 100: "; //Asks guess a number
    cin >> player2;


    while(player2 != player1)
    {
       cout << "Player 2 guess the number between 1 and 100: ";
    }

    system("pause");
    system("pause"); //Keeps window on screen
    return 0;
}
```

Also any feedback on how to make my code better would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It is your while statement.  It should be a do-while around the cout/cin part

Comment: I formatted the code for you and hopefully the error becomes evident.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore With all the respect, I think you should have answered or even rewrote the code you changed below an **EDIT**. You changed the question in a way that the error is way too obvious making the OP looks dumb.

Comment: @Math he might just learn the wonders of proper indentation.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I know indentation is important, but you changed not only it, you put the `cout` inside brackets which (I know) does not alter the flow of the code, but people who do not see the original question will not understand what was the OP doubt. It may have caused him to get some downvotes, maybe.

Comment: It was all indented correctly, pretty much the same as above, but when copying it lost its formatting so I quickly indented so it was all in the same code block.

Comment: @moakeseey with all due respect, the question deserves downvotes. I bet there was no debugging involved, it has no value to future visitors and no effort was put into formatting it. (just a copy-paste) There's no reason for the OP to be upset about it though - I'm just saying it as it is. //OP Next time, put more effort into at least writing the question. As well as debugging. If you don't know how to debug, I suggest you learn. It's one of the most important things you can learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that within the `while` loop you never change the value of `player1` or `player2`.  Hence if they are unequal the first time they will be forever unequal and the code will loop infinitely.  To fix this you need to move the code which changes the values into the body of the loop.  Hence the user has a chance to change the values.

```
do {
  cout << "Player 2 guess the number between 1 and 100: "; //Asks guess a number
  cin >> player2;

  if (player2 == player1)
    cout << "Correct!" << endl;
  else
    cout << "Wrong, try again" << endl;
} while(player2 != player1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You got two things wrong

1. The braces for the while loop.
2. You are not reading user input again in the loop.

Modify the loop as below..

```
    while(player2 != player1)
    {

        cout << "Player 2 guess the number between 1 and 100: ";

        cin >> player2;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use an open brace after the while statement it only refers to the following expression.

Additionally, after the while you are not reading data from the user again, so how do you expect player2 to ever change?

In terms of code organisation it would be better to set player2 to something obviously invalid, like -1, and have the while at the beginning, without the previous read and if statement so it doesn't have to be special cased.

Answer (score 1):

Your `while` has no brackets, which makes the line right after it repeat forever!

Put the `cout` and `cin` for `player 2 guess` inside a `do-while` loop and then verify the condition.

```
cout << "Player 1 type in a number between 1 and 100: "; //Asks player to enter a number
cin  >> player1;
system("CLS");

do {
    cout << "Player 2 guess the number between 1 and 100: ";
    cin >> player2;
} while(player2 != player1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
do
{
  cout << "Player 2 guess the number between 1 and 100: "; //Asks guess a number
  cin >> player2;
} while (player2 != player1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your curly brackets are in the wrong position and you never read input from the player after the first time.

if you change it like this, the second player will be asked again.

....

```
while(player1 != player2){
    cout << "Player 2 guess the number between 1 and 100: ";
    cin >> player2;
}
```

In addition, you should add some basic error handling, for example checking if the cin.error() flag is set.

Answer (score 0):

The loop

```
while(player2 != player1)
{
   cout << "Player 2 guess the number between 1 and 100: ";
}
```

is an endless loop, because the variables player2 and player1 are not changed inside of the loop. If the while condition is true when entering the loop, it will stay true forever.

UPDATE:

To allow player2 to guess repeatedly, and hence change the number that he guessed and get out of the while loop, add `cin >> player2;` after the `cout` statement:

```
while(player2 != player1)
{
    cout << "Player 2 guess the number between 1 and 100: ";
    cin >> player2;
}
```

Comment: if player2 != player1 you've written the c++ version of 
  10 PRINT "Player 2 guess the number between 1 and 100:"
  20 GOTO 10

Comment: @Anonymouse: Yes, the code is a copy-paste from the question and it is my intention that it is bad code, because in my answer, I'm explaining why it is bad code. This is an alright answer. If you downvoted this answer, please reconsider your downvote.

Comment: sorry hand't spotted the original 'question' included those lines... let just agree that this post needs a newbie\homework tag

Comment: that's alright. no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

In

```
while(player2 != player1)
{
cout << "Player 2 guess the number between 1 and 100: ";
}
```

Nothing in the loop ever changes `player2` nor `player1`, so if the condition `player2 != player1` was true, it will remain true.